# How to make ReSharper place delegated get-only properties in a single line?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

It generates:

```
     public GameMode GameType
     {
         get { return _builder.GameType; } }
```

But I want:

```
     public GameMode GameType { get { return _builder.GameType; } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ReSharper's Options, navigate to **Code Editing|C#|Formatting Style|Line Breaks and Wrapping** and look for the setting titled **Place simple property/indexer/event declaration on a single line**.

Comment: It's already checked. ReSharper places the content of "get" or "set" in a single line but doesn't do the same for property name and get/set.

Comment: @Vlad apologies - this is a genuine bug on our end - I've posted an issue report here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-436218